# Why do I keep getting "Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

I'm new to python and the following code is giving me an error: "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath..."". I also tried find_element_by_id and find_element_by_name as well but no luck. I still get an error saying the element cannot be found. Is this because the elements are inside a span class?

```
chrome_path = r"C:\DRIVERS\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("""https://www.dynamiccommunities.com/widgets/generic?cobaltsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fdciug.dynamiccommunities.com%2FLogin.aspx%3FReturnUrl%3D%2FAuthentication%2FHigherLogicLogin.ashx%3FRedirectURL%3Dhttps%3a%2f%2fwww.dynamiccommunities.com%2fhome""")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)


driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="FormContentPlaceHolder_LoginEditForm_UserName"]""").send_keys('test')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="FormContentPlaceHolder_LoginEditForm_Password"]""").send_keys('***')
``
```

Comment: Assuming your xpath is correct, you may also have to wait for the element to load first: `WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_of_element)))`. If this doesn't work, try locating by ID or Class.

Comment: Tried that too but no luck.

Comment: Did you try locating by ID? Using `FormContentPlaceHolder_LoginEditForm_UserName` as ID?

Comment: Yes tried that too. It just times out.

Comment: It's in an iframe.

Comment: Thanks I did not notice that. It works now after I added the following line:
driver.switch_to.frame("cobaltautoIframe_yye5zgjoy")